# How to solve an equation in Python? Which is the equivalent to ode45 for Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, ode, solver, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve an equation in Python. This is an implicit equation and this is not easy to solve. I think that the Matlab command is ode45, but what is the equivalent for Python?
Is there a function that solve easily any kind of equation?

Thank you!!

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html can you check this?

Comment: What do you mean with "implicit"? Do you need to solve an equation to get the top derivative? Do you have values prescribed at different times?

Comment: I have first and second derivative.I discretized the equation and noe I have the function evaluated in x, x-h, x+h. And.... I really don't know how I can solve it... I thought to made a matrix in which in the first row I write the values for t=0 and in the first column x-h, in the second x, and in the third x+h, other columns=0. The second row is made: first column=0, second x-h, third x, fourth x+h, and the others=0, and so on. but I'm not sure I can get the right solution

Answer (score 2):

This is the equivalent to ode45:

[scipy.integrate.solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html)

The way to use it is almost identical:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
    
vdp1 = lambda T,Y : [Y[1], (1 - Y[0]**2) * Y[1] - Y[0]]

sol = solve_ivp (vdp1, [0, 20], [2, 0])
T = sol.t
Y = sol.y
```

Comment: Not entirely, you have to set the argument `method`to `RK45` to recover the ode45 algorithm.

Comment: @Laurent90, `RK45` is the default for function `solve_ivp`.